# Finding a value between two numbers, given percentage, which is bigger when the percentage is smaller

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I'd like to find a way to calculate a value which is between two numbers (100 - 500), and that gets smaller the more the percentage is bigger. This means that 100% should give you 100, while 1% should give you 500.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: percentage of what?

Comment: It's a previous result. I don't think that really matters here.

Comment: so basically you want $f(x)$ such as $f(100)=100$ and $f(1)=500$?

Comment: @Vasya yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linear function $y=ax+b$. Your requirements are: $100=100a+b$ and $500=a+b$. When we solve this system, we find $a$ and $b$ and the function will be: $$y(x)=\frac{49900-400x}{99}$$